# Is there a way I can get a list of all the items with balance variable in django

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have created an API that is being called by my react frontend. So the problem is this I have a viewset that shows a list of all customers in the database which works perfectly. I have also created a retrieve method that shows individual customer details and all the orders purchased. In this retrieve method, I have a variable that shows the balance for the customer. My question is, is there a way I can get a List of all customers with a balance that is greater than 0 and lower than 0

Here is my viewset

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request):
        customer = Customer.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer, many=True, context={"request": request})
        response_dict = {"error": False, "message": "All Customers List Data", "data": serializer.data}
        return Response(response_dict)

    def create(self, request):
        try:
            serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Customer Data Stored Successfully"}
        except:
            dict_response = {"error": True, "message": "Phone Number Exists In Database, Fill All Fields"}

        return Response(dict_response)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()
        customer = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer, context={"request": request})

        serializer_data = serializer.data
        # Accessing All the Orders Details of Current Customer
        orders_details = Orders.objects.filter(customer_id=serializer_data["id"]).order_by('-id')
        orders_details_serializers = OrdersSerializer(orders_details, many=True)
        serializer_data["orders"] = orders_details_serializers.data

        # Accessing All Orders of Current Customer
        orders_count = Orders.objects.filter(customer_id=serializer_data["id"])
        orders_count_serializer = OrdersSerializer(orders_count, many=True, context={"request": request})

        # Total orders amount of current customer
        orders_total = Orders.objects.filter(customer_id=serializer_data["id"])
        amount = 0
        discount = 0
        kgs = 0
        for total in orders_total:
            amount = amount + float(total.amount)
            discount = discount + float(total.discount)
            kgs = kgs + float(total.kgs)

        serializer_data1 = serializer.data
        # Accessing All the Payment Details of Current Customer
        payments_details = Payments.objects.filter(customer_id=serializer_data1["id"]).order_by('-id')
        payments_details_serializers = PaymentsSerializer(payments_details, many=True)
        serializer_data["payments"] = payments_details_serializers.data

        serializer_data2 = serializer_data
        payment_count = Payments.objects.filter(customer_id=serializer_data2["id"])
        payment_count_serializer = PaymentsSerializer(payment_count, many=True, context={"request": request})

        # Total Payment of current customer
        payment_total = Payments.objects.filter(customer_id=serializer_data2["id"])
        t_amount = 0
        for balance in payment_total:
            t_amount = t_amount + float(balance.payment)

        balance = amount - t_amount

        dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Single Data Fetch",
                         "data": serializer_data,
                         "payment": len(payment_count_serializer.data),
                         "buy_total": amount,
                         "payed_total": t_amount,
                         "balance": balance,
                         "kgs": kgs,
                         "discount": discount,
                         "orders_count": len(orders_count_serializer.data)}
        return Response(dict_response)

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            queryset = Customer.objects.all()
            customer = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
            serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer, data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Customer Data Updated Successfully"}
        except:
            dict_response = {"error": True, "message": "An Error Occurred"}

        return Response(dict_response)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()
        customer = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        # serializer = PaymentsSerializer(customer, context={"request": request})
        customer.delete()
        return Response({"error": False, "message": "Customer Deleted"})
```

Any idea or solution on how I can achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you may like

```
from django.db.models import Sum

order = Orders.objects.filter(customer_id=serializer_data['id']).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
total_order_sum = order.get('amount__sum')

payment = Payments.objects.filter(customer_id=serializer_data2["id"])..aggregate(Sum('payment'))
total_payment_sum = payment.get('payment__sum')


balance = float(total_order_sum - total_payment_sum)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Lets say I have 50 customers in my database and out of those 50, 20 have a balance that is lees than 0, How can I retrieve those 20 customers and list them considering I'm calculating the balanceof individual customer

Comment: Order.objects.filter(amount__lte=0).values_list('customer_id', flat=True)

This qs return list of customer_ids whose amount is less than or equal to 0.